# Finding repeated lines in Python

Tags: python, file

I've got a txt file which has some lines, I want to find out:

Does this file have the same lines?

For example, These are my lines:

```
7924265e2024daa24f801290d070a519
f1cbfec6b396152da87e6a4279a4ad81
8d1a705ed05f734a03e890db5467ea0a
021128daa2fb3dc8b7c5af9e49e24439
e2ec22e390c5910eb4e952208bb1c47d
8d1a705ed05f734a03e890db5467ea0a
7f65a7f8a160431cc8f69cd1f04b0aba
d8e5f74f296cd47a30915bbbd2418d66
005f8b973ebe30fd19b1bf802ffb6b32
```

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: If you want to get a proper answer you need to update your answer with the code that you've tried and tell us about the problem with your code. Also this question as a lot of duplicate and similar questions in SO.

Comment: Thank you @Kasramvd, I'll do it, of course, at first I'll test the code you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have read in the lines and stored them in an array

```
lines
```

Then,

```
set(lines)
```

gives you a set that contains all unique lines. If every line is unique the length of lines and set(lines) will be the same. Ergo:

```
if len(lines) == len(set(lines)):
      print 'all lines are unique'
   else:
      print 'not all lines are unique'
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm:

```
with open("file","r") as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            print(line)
        else:
            seen.add(line_lower)
```